# Read text in java script

Tags: javascript, filereader

What is a typical method for reading text files in javascript? The file will be located on the server like the rest of the script files, but I want to use it as GLSL shaders for instance.

I thought I could simply replace this:

```
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    //GLSL code
</script>
```

with this line:

```
<script id="shader-vs2" type="x-shader/x-vertex" src="../Data/Effects/Shader.vp"></script>
```

When I tried it on Chrome it resulted in the following error.

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "https://c9.io/b_old/substitute/workspace/Data/Effects/Shader.vp".

How should this be done?

I suppose what I really want is a XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Is the server your hosting the file on serving the file with MIME type `x-shader/x-vertex`? Looks like it's sending the default `application/octet-stream` type.

Comment: I changed the expected MIME type to application/octet-stream because I don't really care about the type. Chrome doesn't complain anymore, but the shader compiler gives an unexpected EOF error.
Why can't I just load a simple text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what I really want is a XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your web server to transfer *.vp files as `x-shader/x-vertex`.

For example in apache you would configure something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
AddType x-shader/x-vertex vp
```

Other web servers have their own ways to configure this. [IIS Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is here if you're using it.

Comment: I'm not using any web-server. This is just javascript executed locally.

Comment: "../Data/Effects/Shader.vp"
This is relative to the html containing the rest of the code.

Comment: But in your original question the error says that the file is on a a path with https protocol. Confused.

Comment: Sorry. Then I was editing/executing from a web based editor called cloud9. Shader.vp is still relative to the html though.